Parallelizability of SU(3)
I'm perplexed by some apparently conflicting results.  It has been known since the 90's that SU(3) is topologically a fiber bundle of S3's fibered onto S5 (e.g. based on results in Steenrod's book.) Easily seen heuristically from the form of the matrices and the SU(2) within them and proved in arxiv:hep-th/9812006v1. It is also well-known, and cited many places, such as Wikipedia, the Encyclopedia of Math, and others, that all Lie groups are parallelizable, while S1, S3, and S7 are known to be the only parallelizable unit spheres, so S5 is not. So what's up with SU(3)?  How can it be both? Is the conflict only apparent? Some error or omission in this logic or my understanding of it? Is it because the S3 fibers are, and somehow that's sufficient for the proof of parallelizability of Lie groups? S5 can safely be ignored as the base of the bundle?

I don’t see the contradiction. Why would a topological fibre bundle of a parallelizable manifold over a parallelizable base be parallelizable?

I have to admit (as a non-expert) that even in the smooth category, I don’t see how one could glue vector fields over a fibration. This seems like something with a homotopical obstruction.

"How can it be both?" - both what? Do you find it surprising that a bundle over a non-parallelizable manifold is parallelizable? An easier example is $S^3$ which is a circle bundle over $S^2$.

Surely $SU(3)$'s structure as a fiber bundle was known long before the 90s?

The  Klein bottle is a circle bundle over the circle, but is not parallelizable(not orientable)

@QY   Yes, I believe it was too, from many comments I've run across.  Almost certainly known to Steenrod and those whose work he consolidated in his book.  He discusses that specific bundle without (so far as I've found) connecting it to SU(3). The citation I gave is the only one  I've ever found to any written work confirming it.   My access to pre-Internet math literature is severely llimited. It could well be somewhere there in the '60's or '70's literature.

There is no contradiction. A parallelization of $SU(3)$ simply does not "descend" to a parallelization of $S^5$ in any way. This would require some kind of compatibility with the $S^3$ fibers (don't ask me what that means explicitly) which isn't necessarily the case (and can't be, as the general results you cited imply).
Edit: Okay, this deserves an elaboration. We can consider the following general situation: suppose $G$ is a connected Lie group and $H \subset G$ is a connected Lie subgroup (in your example $G = SU(3), H = SU(2)$). Then we can consider the homogeneous space $G/H$, which is the base space of a fiber bundle
$$H \to G \to G/H.$$
For example if $G = SU(n), H = SU(n-1)$ then $G/H \cong S^{2n-1}$ is the Hermitian unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^n$; this gives your example by setting $n = 3$.
Now connected Lie groups are always parallelizable; the translation action of $G$ on itself can be used to smoothly identify every tangent space with the Lie algebra $T_e(G) \cong \mathfrak{g}$. So $H$ and $G$ in the above diagram are always parallelizable. But $G/H$ is not in general, as the sphere examples show.
One might ask:

It seems like it ought to be possible to smoothly identify the tangent spaces of $G/H$ with the quotient $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h} \cong T_{eH}(G/H)$ (of vector spaces), somehow combining the parallelizations above to parallelize $G/H$. Why doesn't this work?

My grasp of the geometry here is not as good as it could be but here is what I think happens. Suppose you pick an arbitrary point in $G/H$, given by some coset $gH$, and you want to identify its tangent space with $T_{eH}(G/H) \cong \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$. You'd like to do this via some translation to get back to the identity coset, but you can translate via (the inverse of) any element of the coset $gH$ and there is no obvious way to pick one. To get a compatible smooth family of choices you'd need a smooth section of the fiber bundle $G \to G/H$, which is some principal $H$-bundle and which does not necessarily admit a smooth section. (I think this $H$-bundle actually determines the tangent bundle of $G/H$, in the sense that the tangent bundle is the associated bundle associated to the representation $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ of $H$, where $H$ acts adjointly.)
In the $S^5$ case we have a principal $SU(2)$-bundle over $S^5$ which is classified by some homotopy class of maps $S^5 \to BSU(2)$, hence by an element of $\pi_4(S^3) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, which does not vanish, so there is a nontrivial bundle (and it must be this one).
An alternative more geometric idea is to use the trivialization of $G$ and see what it does to the subspace $T_e(H) \cong \mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g} \cong T_e(G)$. I have not done the calculation but I believe what happens is that at $g \in G$, the parallelization conjugates this subspace to $g \mathfrak{h} g^{-1}$. And this conjugation action can be nontrivial in that we can get a different subspace. So it looks to me like we do not get a parallelization of $G/H$ this way unless $H$ is normal in $G$, in which case $G/H$ is again a Lie group and so admits a Lie group parallelization.

Thanks to all for the comments and answer.  Clearly my misconception was that the parallelizability of SU(3) was connected to or dependent in any way on that of the unit spheres it "contains", i.e. of its subspaces.   Thanks again for the clarifications.
